# Insert from Staging to Final only if more recent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't come up with a proper query for this `insert` problem

I have a table `Final`

And I have a `Stg` table. I want to insert `Stg` into `Final` only if

`Stg.Date > MAX(Final.Start)` -> `placeholder for Pilot (P)` for each `Destination` and `Stg.Pilot <> (P)`
Initial `Final` table

[image]

Assume `Stg.Destination` is Unique

Ex1:
Since both Stg entries Date field > than their corresponding max field in Final, both are inserted

[image]

Ex2:
Since Stg.Date for Denver < 4/10/2020, we skip it; Atlanta meet contraints, it is added

[image]

Ex3:
Denver is added; Atlanta not, since Stg.Pilot=E, which equals to MaxDate row in Final

[image]

Tables for the first example:

```
Create table Final
(Destination VARCHAR(55), Pilot VARCHAR(55), Date Date)

Create table Stg
(Destination VARCHAR(55), Pilot VARCHAR(55), Date Date)

INSERT Final Values

('Denver',  'A',    '4/1/2020'   ) ,
('Denver',  'B',    '4/5/2020'   ) ,
('Denver',  'C',    '4/7/2020'   ) ,
('Denver',  'A',    '4/10/2020'  ) ,
('Atlanta', 'C',    '4/2/2020'   ) ,
('Atlanta', 'D',    '4/4/2020'   ) ,
('Atlanta', 'E',    '4/8/2020'   )


INSERT Stg Values
('Denver',  'F',    '4/13/2020'  ) ,
('Atlanta', 'G',    '4/9/2020'   )
```

Here is my try, but things seem not to work properly

```
  WITH Test AS (SELECT Destination,Pilot,Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Pilot, ORder by Date Desc) as rn FROM Final)
  INSERT INTO Final (Destination,Pilot,Date)
  SELECT s.Destination,s.Pilot,s.Date
  FROM   Stg s
  JOIN   Test t on s.Destination = t.Destination AND r.rn = 1 AND s.Date > t.Date and s.Pilot <> t.Pilot
```

Comment: @DaleK , added my try. If Stg.Pilot is the same as the pilot with max Date for the Destionation, we don't add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think rather than an `inner join` you want a `not exists`. Also you were partitioning over `Pilot` whereas from your question I understand you to want to partition over `Description` e.g.

```
declare @Final table (Destination VARCHAR(55), Pilot VARCHAR(55), [Date] Date);
declare @Stg table (Destination VARCHAR(55), Pilot VARCHAR(55), [Date] Date);

INSERT into @Final Values
('Denver',  'A',    '4/1/2020'   ),
('Denver',  'B',    '4/5/2020'   ),
('Denver',  'C',    '4/7/2020'   ),
('Denver',  'A',    '4/10/2020'  ),
('Atlanta', 'C',    '4/2/2020'   ),
('Atlanta', 'D',    '4/4/2020'   ),
('Atlanta', 'E',    '4/8/2020'   );

INSERT into @Stg Values
('Denver',  'F',    '4/13/2020'  ),
('Atlanta', 'G',    '4/7/2020'   );

--select * from @Final;
--select * from @Stg;

WITH Test AS (
  SELECT Destination, Pilot, [Date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Destination ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rn
  FROM @Final
)
--select * from Test where rn = 1
INSERT INTO @Final (Destination, Pilot, [Date])
SELECT S.Destination, S.Pilot, S.[Date]
FROM @Stg S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Test T
  WHERE rn = 1
  AND S.Destination = T.Destination
  AND (
    T.Pilot = S.Pilot
    OR T.[Date] >= S.[Date]
  )
);

select * from @Final order by Destination, [Date];
```

Gives, as required:

```
Destination | Pilot | Date
------------------------------
Atlanta     | C     | 2020-04-02
Atlanta     | D     | 2020-04-04
Atlanta     | E     | 2020-04-08
Atlanta     | G     | 2020-04-09
Denver      | A     | 2020-04-01
Denver      | B     | 2020-04-05
Denver      | C     | 2020-04-07
Denver      | A     | 2020-04-10
Denver      | F     | 2020-04-13
```

Comment: your first answer was correct, but with EXISTS , since above doesn't work for Ex3 `INSERT Stg Values
('Denver', 'J', '4/11/2020'  ) ,
('Atlanta', 'E', '4/11/2020'  ) `